# How to get dropdown with list of colors?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#9724; Dark blue</option>
  <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; Turquoise</option>
  <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; Green</option>
  <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; Yellow</option>
  <option style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#9724; Orange</option>
  <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; Red</option>
  <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; Black</option>
</select>
```

Colors not showing do I need to install some plugins? I want to achieve this but I'm getting black box only [image]

Comment: Your example works fine in Chrome 96.

Comment: @Jax-p it does when you open the options list, but not when you have selected something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply the selected color to the selectbox. This can be easily achieved with JS via the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

```js
const colorBox = document.getElementById('color');

colorBox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const color = event.target.value;
  event.target.style.color = color;
}, false);
```

```html
<select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#9724; Dark blue</option>
<option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; Turquoise</option>
<option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; Green</option>                         
<option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; Yellow</option>
<option style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#9724; Orange</option>
<option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; Red</option>
<option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; Black</option>                       
</select>
```

Comment: Or in one line `document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', function() {  this.style.color = this.value });`